# How to remove a python module and its dependencies that is installed a specific directory?

Tags: python, pip

When I install a python module at a specific directory. Is there a command to remove the module and its dependencies? I know that I can remove it by deleting the directory.

```
pip install requests -t ./libs
```

Comment: Assuming you used pip to install it, `pip uninstall module` should remove it.

Comment: `pip uninstall module` doesn't seem to remove a module installed at a specific directory if I am not mistaken.

Comment: If you used `pip install` with some option to install the module in a nonstandard location, then I imagine you can use that same option with `pip uninstall` to remove the module.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
PYTHONPATH=libs pip uninstall -y requests
```

It's not a complete solutions — when I did an experiment `pip` tried to uninstall a non-existing scripts from `/usr/bin` (the scripts were actually in `./lib/bin`).

So it seems `rm -rf ./libs` is the only real solution.